# Reflections on moving water

Tags: xna, water, waves

I've been working on a simple game with semi-realistic water. I followed some tutorials to get:

- a flat water surface
- reflection and refraction (blended using fresnel term)
- ripples using a bump/normal map

Next step, I created a mesh to form actual waves. I'm animating it, and it looks great (for my intents and purposes).

Normally, to get the reflection, I would render everything on a second camera, which is actually the normal camera, but mirrored over the water plane, like in the image below:
[image: Reflection explained]

Then, just sample that camera's output to find the reflected color.
Obviously, this technique doesn't work if the water level isn't consistent. In other words, with an animated mesh, this looks terrible.

Can anybody suggest a different way to implement reflections? Or show a workaround method?

Comment: rendering the camera B on the water mesh texture?

Comment: Could you explain? I don't understand how that would work.

Comment: Sorry , i thinked of Unity, where you can render a camera output into a texture

Comment: Maybe you could use a cubemap.

Comment: I've looked into cubemaps, but it seems like that would only work for a single point or a relatively small 3d object around said point. As far as I can tell, cubemaps dont work for planar surfaces.

Comment: I have an idea. Maybe I could make it so that when I render the mirrored version, I just mirror everything but the camera, using custom shaders. I could mirror everything along the local waterheight since I have a bump map. I'm going to try this out and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference: I solved this problem by mirroring everything over the local waterheight instead of a plane. I rendered all that using the standard camera.